# react-native-admob:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: react-native

I was migrating from the expo to RN in expo app was running fine but in RN when I run my app I got following error

```
> Task :react-native-admob:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
12 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 9 up-to-date
F:\project\react native\MyApp\node_modules\react-native-admob\android\src\main\java\com\sbugert\rnadmob\RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule.java:20: error: RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule is not abstract and does not override abstract method onRewardedVideoCompleted() in RewardedVideoAdListener
public class RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
       ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```